# How to create conditional values for a variable based on another variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements, recode

I'd like to make a conditional 0/1 variable in my dataset, based on the value of another variable. My Ifeslse statements aren't working

```
If Repeat > 3, then fast = 0

If Repeat < 3, then fast = 1
```

I'm getting the correct output, in the form as "TRUE" "FALSE" in my bottom readout box, but the values in my data set aren't changing

I've tried my "Repeat" variable as numeric and as a factor

```
as.factor(dat1$Repeat)


f.s = 1
numb.repeat$f.s = 1
as.numeric(numb.repeat$f.s)


ifelse(numb.repeat$Repeat > 3, numb.repeat$f.s == 0, numb.repeat$f.s ==1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column you want to assign using `ifelse` should appear on the LHS (left hand side) of the `ifelse` expression:

```
numb.repeat$f.s <- ifelse(numb.repeat$Repeat > 3, 0, 1)
```

But actually, you don't even need `ifelse` here:

```
numb.repeat$f.s <- numb.repeat$Repeat <= 3
```